# How do you find all the redirects that led someone to a webpage via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

A little background here, my team and I are currently developing a web extension that needs to know what URLs a user went through to arrive at the page they are currently on. https://www.ayima.com/us/insights/seo/redirect-checker.html does exactly what we need it to but their source code is not available online. Is there anyway to leverage the functionality from an extension in another extension? Or is there a better way to go about this using a Node library? document.referrer would only give me the last URL they were on, but I need every redirect a user went through, and in our use case it can be 3 or more URLs.

Comment: `a Node library` - I can't see how a node library would help - node runs on the server, it has no way of peeking at the history of a browser - are all these URLs on your server? then of course you can track a user through your own site

Comment: They are not on our server, it could be any random site. We need to know every url/site they went through to arrive at the site they are currently on.

Comment: See chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.

Comment: so you'll need to track every redirect on every tab for an unspecified (3 or more) chain of redirects?

Comment: Not every redirect on every tab. Just the active tab. For example, a user clicks a link on a page, and they are navigated to a different page but there are 3 or however many intermediary pages they pass through before arriving on a new page. I need to know every URL they visited before they landed on the page they are on.

Comment: chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect seems like what I may need, will dig into that more, thanks wOxxOm